# How can I make the height rise (slide up) and make the content reveal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I was playing for a long time today, trying to accomplish something without knowledge.
However I have made an JS fiddle with this explanation, so I hope someone can help me.

Let's get to the point.

I have 4 small boxes. Each box is 15x15px just like in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7fPD/2/).

```
<div class="js-fiddleWrap">
    <div id="letterA">Letter A opened-content.</div>
    <div id="letterB">Letter B opened-content.</div>
    <div id="letterC">Letter C opened-content.</div>
    <div id="letterD">Letter D opened-content.</div>
    
    <nav class="collapseMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>​
```

On click of one box animation starts and box becomes higher(longer) and gets 45px instead of 15px. It also goes up so it looks like it is rising using this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $collapseMenu = $('.collapseMenu li');

    $collapseMenu.on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'bottom': '30',
            'height': '45',
        });
    });
});​
```

Although I made this, I think it's wrong. After this animation, theres more that I wasn't able to accomplish.

I have some hidden content just like in fiddle. Example A, B, C and D content.
So each box that is clicked rise up, reveal content and then hides the content if same or different box has been clicked.

Also I wasn't able to create minimize back effect. Mean if same box is clicked again once it has risen up and revealed content, it will go back to default position. As well, same thing will happened if different box is clicked. It will hide previously opened box and minimize it.

#### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7fPD/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H7fPD/4/)**

**jQuery**

```
var $collapseMenu = $('.collapseMenu li');
$collapseMenu.on('click', function() {
    $collapseMenu.stop(true,true).animate({
        'bottom': '0',
        'height': '15'
    });
    if($(this).height() != 45 ) $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        'bottom': '30',
        'height': '45'
    });
});​
```

Comment: This is quite great even tho I cannot quite understand it.
However only one trouble left in this case.
Content fadeIn and Out :) 
I will try to solve last trouble. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use .toggle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $collapseMenu = $('.collapseMenu li');

    $collapseMenu.toggle(
//odd clicks
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'bottom': '30',
            'height': '45',
        });
    },
//even clicks
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'bottom': '0',
            'height': '15',
        });
    });

});​
```

Now you can add additional logic to it to check if any of the other boxes are toggled, or simply set all the other boxes to bottom:0; height:15; on click of any of the boxes

Comment: Cheers infinity. Tried this example as well. Works quite same as the example from j08691.